# Where is table data stored in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

Hi I'm trying to find out where SparkSQL stores the table metadata in Spark?  If it is not in the Hive metastore by default, then where is it stored?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is explanation from spark-2.2.0 documentation

When not configured by `hive-site.xml`, the context automatically creates `metastore_db` in the current directory and creates a directory configured by `spark.sql.warehouse.dir`, which defaults to the directory spark-warehouse in the current directory that the Spark application is started. Note that the `hive.metastore.warehouse.dir` property in `hive-site.xml` is deprecated since Spark 2.0.0. Instead, use `spark.sql.warehouse.dir` to specify the default location of database in warehouse.

Here is the link:
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-hive-tables.html

Comment: I'm talking about table metadata not the table data

Comment: Yes, meta data or metastore is the same. like derby db that is used by hive. I added the link of the official documentation in my answer.

Comment: Also, metastore_db seems to be derby formatted because spark will generate derby.log file. You can check this post:https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SS3H8V_1.1.0/com.ibm.izoda.v1r1.azka100/topics/azkic_t_updconfigfiles.htm

Comment: If something is stored under the 'default' db in Spark, it doesn't show up in the same path as whatever is defined against "spark.sql.warehouse.dir".
Where can we find those?